# The lightest, stiffest, and largest panels available are made of what?

Tags: acoustics, vibrations, material-science

[This document on audio exciters](http://www.parts-express.com/pedocs/more-info/hiwave-exciter-guidelines-more-info.pdf) lays out some uncited requirements for the best sound from an excited panel:

- A stiffer panel will give better high frequency (treble) performance.
- A lighter panel will make a speaker that plays louder.
- A larger panel will give better low frequency (bass) performance.

The exciter can vibrate anything from steel to foam to corrugated plastic. I might wonder how a paper-thin 50 foot slice of diamond would sound, but in practice I need to buy some kind of panel in a store or online. What material best meets these goals? What best meets only two of the goals?